# AutoMapper 12.0.1 Update Causes AssertConfigurationIsValid() Failures with Custom Value Resolvers

Tags: c#, automapper

I have encountered an issue after updating AutoMapper from version `10.0.1` to `12.0.1`. The following code is part of my mapping profile, which previously functioned correctly. However, after the update, I am receiving errors when invoking `AssertConfigurationIsValid()`:

```cs
CreateMap<CreateCodesetRequest, Codeset>(MemberList.Source)
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => NameableResolver.Trim(src.Name)))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.NormalizedName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name.ToNormalizedString()))
    .ForSourceMember(src => src.Visibility, opt => opt.DoNotValidate());

CreateMap<UpdateCodesetRequest, Codeset>(MemberList.Source)
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => NameableResolver.Trim(src.Name)))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.CodeGroupType, opt => opt.MapFrom<UpdateCodesetGroupTypeResolver>())
    .ForSourceMember(src => src.Visibility, opt => opt.DoNotValidate());
```

Error Messages:

```
CreateCodesetRequest -> Codeset (Source member list)
DHC.Platypus.Services.Customize.Messages.Requests.Codesets.CreateCodesetRequest ->
DHC.Platypus.Services.Customize.Messages.Models.Codeset (Source member list)

Unmapped properties:
Name
```

```
UpdateCodesetRequest -> Codeset (Source member list)
DHC.Platypus.Services.Customize.Messages.Requests.Codesets.UpdateCodesetRequest ->
DHC.Platypus.Services.Customize.Messages.Models.Codeset (Source member list)

Unmapped properties:
Name
CodeGroupType
```

When I bypass the functions and resolver by mapping the fields directly, I do not encounter any errors during assertion:

```cs
CreateMap<CreateCodesetRequest, Codeset>(MemberList.Source)
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.NormalizedName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name.ToNormalizedString()))
    .ForSourceMember(src => src.Visibility, opt => opt.DoNotValidate());

CreateMap<UpdateCodesetRequest, Codeset>(MemberList.Source)
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.CodeGroupType, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CodeGroupType))
    .ForSourceMember(src => src.Visibility, opt => opt.DoNotValidate());
```

What steps can I take to ensure that my custom conversions work and that `AssertConfigurationIsValid()` passes without errors?

Comment: Probably best to post in the AutoMapper github discussion forum https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/discussions.

Comment: Instead of a resolver, you can use a value transformer.